# flutter how I return list from future

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to return a List from a Future based on data snapshots I'm getting from Firestore. I manage to build a nice list with a loop, but cannot access it from UI widgets.

I'm creating a Future in a FSservice.dart:

```
Future<List> newsCollection() async {

    List docList = [];
    List testNewList = [];

    try {
      final CollectionReference news = _fire.collection('news');
      return await news.get().then((value) {

      news.snapshots().listen((event) {

        for (final child in event.docs) {
          docList.add(child.id);
        }

        for (final index in docList) {
          print(index);

          final docRef = news.doc(index);
          docRef.get().then (
              (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                final docData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                testNewList.add(docData);
              });
        }
      });
      return testNewList;
    });


    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw ('sth is wrong');
    }
```

Then I'm calling newsCollection() inside a news.dart stateful widget, where I place UI logic:

```
    List<dynamic> testNewList = [];
final FireServ fireServ = FireServ();
    
    Future getNewList() async {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
        testNewList = fireServ.newsCollection() as List;
      }
```

and initiate it in initState():

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getNewList();
    super.initState();
  }
```

I see that list builds up nicely over the loop, but I cannot access data. When I print testNewList - it is empty :(

When I remove cast, I'm getting error that Future<List> cannot be assigned to List.

If I had this list I would parse it over a model class and it should work...but I'm stuck here :(

Can you help me out with this issue?

I handled this process on Firebase Realtime DB, but somehow struggle with Firestore.

**EDIT:**

I managed to improve the code, although still not getting objects outside Future:

```
final CollectionReference news = _fire.collection('news');
  return await news.get().then((value) {
    print(value.docs.toList());

    for (final child in value.docs) {
      docList.add(child.id);
    }

    for (final index in docList) {
      final docRef = news.doc(index);
      docRef.get().then (
              (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
            final docData = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print(docData);
            testNewList.add(docData);
            print(testNewList);
            print(testNewList.length);
          });
    }

    print(docList);
    print(testNewList);
    return testNewList;
  });
```

The list builds inside the loop, but Future does not return it (it is not void now).

**EDIT**

Again - code improvement :) -> I changed the second loop and now it looks like this:

```
for (final index in docList) {
          final docRef = news.doc(index);
          testNewList.add(
              docRef.get().then (
                      (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                        print(doc.data());
                        final docData = doc.data();
                        return docData;
                      }));
```

and returns Futures in testNewList variable:

```
[Instance of 'Future<Object?>', Instance of 'Future<Object?>', Instance of 'Future<Object?>']
```

any ideas how to get these futures? I'm trying with async body of then and await before docData return, but it is not working. When I print doc.data() inside loop I see a full object, but when it is added to a list it becomes a Future<Object?>

Comment: Call setState to update state: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here's working future inside fireservice:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> newsCollection2() async {

    List docList = [];
    List testNewList = [];

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

    try {
      final CollectionReference news = _fire.collection('news');
      await news.get().then((value) {
        // print(value.docs.toList());

        for (final child in value.docs) {
          docList.add(child.id);
        }});

        for (final index in docList) {
          final docRef = news.doc(index);
          testNewList.add(
              await docRef.get().then (
                      (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                        // print(doc.data());
                        final docData = doc.data();
                        return docData;
                      })
          );
        }

        print(docList);
        print(testNewList);
        return await testNewList;


    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw ('sth is wrong');
    }
  }
```

I had to add 'await' in front of 'docRef' and it works like a charm ;) now I have to return this list inside UI :D